# Executing a command on server

Tags: php, android, .net

I am developing an handwriting recog tool for android and I have planned to use a server for this purpose. I will be getting data from the android interface and send it to the server where it's stored in a file. I have a toolkit written in c which I will be using and I have to execute a few commands which will have text files as its parameters.

An example of a command:

> HVite -A -D -T 1 -H C:\htk\model\hmm0\Single.mmf -i C:\htk\data\train\lab\1.mlf -w C:\htk\def\net.slf C:\htk\def\dict.txt C:\htk\model\hmm0\hmmlist.txt C:\htk\data\train\user\h1.txt

Where `single.mmf`, `1.mlf`, `net.slf`, `hmmlist.txt` are the parameters to the command `hvite`. Is there a way to execute such commands on server and if yes what are the proposed solutions?

Secondly is sending data from android to the server and then doing all the processing on the server side a good choice? I would have to post the result back to android as well.

Comment: Are the command parameters coming from the Android app?

Comment: I dont think so , as we will create a text file on server which will contain data coming from android and pass it as a parameter , secondly will there be any trouble while connecting emulator to local server

Comment: From what do you want to execute the command: PHP, C?

Comment: my exe which i want to run is written in C but i  will call it from php ,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this command http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pcntl-exec.php and notice that "Executes specified program in current process space" - this limits your program and on the other hand gives you safe environment. You may also want to look at this list http://php.net/manual/en/book.exec.php

Comment: Hmm and what about simple exec command does it take parameters as well ?

Comment: according to [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) it does not support arguments. but you could generate something like 'hvite ' . firstfile . ' ' . second file;   and then you would get the desired behavior.

Comment: i didnot get the syntax you mentioned for generating something i mean can you explain it a bit

Comment: its appending a string `exec('HVite ' . $firstFile . ' ' . $secondFile ....);` - i hope this looks better.

Comment: Ok another issue i am worried about my web prog teacher told me that they tried to run command from apache server on windows and it did not work due to permission problem , they tried hard but according to him itmworked fine on linux , is there any such problem on windows when using apache and can it be solved if i use IIS

Comment: i have no idea - never used IIS. but that's a different question.   i'll appreciate it if you accept\up-vote this answer :)